# Candidate template ignored: could not match 'const type-parameter-0-0 *' against 'char'

Tags: c++, arrays, function, templates

I want to make my own library and I have some problems with template function's.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SMKLibrary.h"

int main() {
    char a[5] = {"ASFD"};

    array_print(a,5);

    return 0;
}
```

SMKLibrary.h

```
#ifndef SMKLIBRARY_H
#define SMKLIBRARY_H

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void array_print(const T * array[], int size);

#endif
```

SMKLibrary.cpp

```
#include "SMKLibrary.h"

template <typename T>
void array_print(const T * array[], int size) {
    int last = size - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << array[last] << std::endl;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why I have this error?

Comment: Related (not to the error asked about): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void array_print(const T * array[], int size);
```

Request a pointer to an array.  When the compiler looks at how the function is called it sees `a` which is an array not a pointer to an array.  The types do not match so the template deduction fails.  To fix this drop the `*` from the function so you have

```
void array_print(const T array[], int size);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make function deduce array size from its argument:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t size>
void array_print(T(&array)[size]) {
    int last = size - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << array[last] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char a[5] = {"ASFD"};
    array_print(a);
}
```

also the next problem you will encounter after fixing compilation error, is linker error. As πάντα ῥεῖ said in comments, you need to move your function definition to header file.